# Typescript - modify style of firstChild of element

Tags: css, typescript

I have issue with styling firstChild of element in typescript file - here is my code:

```
let element= document.getElementById("element")
element.children[0].style.height = "80px"
```

HTML:

```
<div id="element">
    <div id="element0"></div>
    <div id="element1"></div>
    <div id="element2"></div>
</div>
```

And the error, which I get in VSC:
Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'

Comment: Can you share us your html?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't thought it's important, I added it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Element` type does not have a `style` property. To get access to it, you need to cast to `HTMLElement`. The way I recommend doing is via generics, like so:

```js
const child = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("#element :first-child")
child.style = ...
```

Or by a cast:

```
const child = document.getElementById("element").children[0] as HTMLElement
child.style = ...
```

Comment: I was trying to apply this soultion, but when I try to log in console `document.getElementById("element :first-child")` it returns null

Comment: @javi I copypasted too much. I fixed the second solution. Both ways are worth knowing,

Answer (score 0):

use css selector instead

```js
let firstChild = document.querySelector("#element :first-child");
firstChild.style.height = "80px";
```

Comment: Still have same error

Comment: @javi my bad, i forgot the space, it should work now, check my edit. thanks

Comment: Thanks for trying help, but even after correction still have same error :C